# Problems implementing BlockingQueue from scratch

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, blockingqueue

I'm trying to build my own variant of BlockingQueue based off the one [found here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/blocking-queues.html).

```
public class ThreadSafeContainer<E> {
private Node front;
private Node end;
private int capacity;
private int size;

public ThreadSafeContainer(int capacity) {
    size = 0;
    this.capacity = capacity;
}

public synchronized void add(E item) {
    while (size == capacity) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (size == 0) {
        notifyAll();
    }

    Node tmp = new Node(item);

    if (end == null) {
        front = tmp;
        end = tmp;
    } else {
        end.next = tmp;
        end = end.next;
    }

    size++;
}

public synchronized E remove() {
    while (size == 0) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (size == capacity) {
        notifyAll();
    }

    E item = front.item;
    front = front.next;
    size--;
    return item;
}

private class Node {
    E item;
    Node next;

    public Node(E item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

But for some reason when I try to run threads like so

```
    Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            queue.add(1);
            queue.add(2);
        }
    };

    Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(queue.remove());
            System.out.println(queue.remove());
        }
    };
```

I get this exception

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at ThreadSafeContainer.remove(ThreadSafeContainer.java:52)
>       at ThreadPractice$2.run(ThreadPractice.java:17)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I can remove the error by changing the size == 0 to front == null but it still doesnt output the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @bradimus Functionally, my code should behave identically except instead of using a pre-existing list structure I've designed my own. The size++/-- should mirror the effects of the example I used. However his runs fine whereas mine has errors.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, if a call to `remove()` ever removes the last element, you end up with `front == null` but `end == //the last created node`.  Which means the next call to `add` will only update `end`, not `front`, and the corresponding call to `remove()` will throw your NPE.

You can either check for `front == null` at the end of `remove()`, or change the test in `add` from `end == null` to `size == 0` or `front == null`.

As an aside, if you're posting a stack trace, it's helpful to add a comment indicating which line in your snippet corresponds to the line numbers in the exception.